# lua table string concat not correct

Tags: lua

I have a simple function to read lines from .txt file:

```
    function loadData(file_name, root_path)
    -- here, file_name is './list.txt', path is '../data/my/'
    
    
        for line in io.lines(file_name) do
            local data = {}
            base_path = root_path .. line
            -- so, base_path is something like  ../data/my/001
            data.file = base_path .. '_color.png'
            print(data)
        end
    end
```

I expect the data should be **{file: "../data/my/001_color.png"}**, but I got **{_color.png" ../data/my/001}**

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Well, this code has syntax errors: stray `:` after the `function` specifier and two missing `end`s. But, assuming that those are typos, and assuming that `list.txt` just has the lines "`001\n002\n --...`", this code seems to work fine. You need `print(data.file)` to see the new path strings, but I assume that you got that right, too, or you would have seen table identifiers. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: @exnihilo Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, those were typos. I print(data), but the outcome is {_color.png" ../data/my/001}. I don't know why _color.png appears in the beginning. And there is only one " symbo.

Comment: That can't be right; `data` is a table, and when you `print(data)` it you will see something like: `table: 0x5605ec3ef230`. I just created a `list.txt` file, loaded your code into a Lua interpreter, and did `loadData('./list.txt', '../data/my/')`. The REPL printed out a list of tables just like `table: 0x5652f0b54a30`. Something else is going on.

Comment: And if I change `print(data)` to `print(data.file)`, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @exnihilo Thank you. I don't know what happened with my ubuntu 16. I also met the same issue (string concat incorrectly) when I used Matlab.

Comment: Can you provide content of file: `./list.txt`, as it may contain special characters? The other thing: your `print` is not standard lua print and assume it is broken. What you see if use `print('{file:"'..data.file..'"}')` instead of `print(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `./list.txt` file content for EOL (end of line) as it may be produced on windows (EOL=CR LF) an interpreted on linux (EOL=LF). `io.lines` takes CR character into line string on linux!

Your programm makes everything correct, but your data is not.

Let assume your first line in `./list.txt` is `../data/my/001\r\n`
`line` variable is `../data/my/001\r` (`print(#line)` gives 15 instead of 14 ).
Carriage return (CR) in `print` moves cursor to start line position witout changing line.
Your `print` output in this case is something simmilar to `{file: "../data/my/001\r_color.png"}` (as it depends on `print` implementation) and you get output:

```
{file: "../data/my/001
_color.png"}                 <-- on the same line
```

Let's combine it:

```
_color.png"}ata/my/001
```

To correct this:

- provide file **without** CR (works correctly on all systems)
- add in loop on first row: `line = line:gsub('[\r\n]','')` to remove CR LF

Comment: The `io.lines` iterator removes line endings. Maybe, if the text file were created on a Mac, and OP is using Linux, this could be a problem. Or if OP has a somehow-broken installation. [OP also commented that they had a similar problem using Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63444210/lua-table-string-concat-not-correct#comment112198435_63444210). Suspicious....

Comment: `io.lines` removes OS related line endings. In linux CR has nothing to do with line ending as it is a control chracter like many others

Comment: Right. That is why I said that if the text file was created on a Mac (with `\r` line endings) and transported to a Linux system where the code is run, there could be a problem.